# in OpenBravo, how do I handle exceptions on a remote call with OB.RemoteCallManager.call

Tags: javascript, java, openbravo

for example, how would I catch exceptions in the server side and display a message?

```
OB.RemoteCallManager.call('org.openbravo.client.application.examples.MyActionHandler', {}, {}, callback);
```

where callback is

```
var callback = function(rpcResponse, data, rpcRequest) {
    isc.say('The result is : ' + data.result);
};
```